# Partially updating complex types in a RESTful Service

Tags: web-services, json, rest, post, put

I am using JSON with RESTful service. Implementation is like this.

GET on http://hostname/a returns

```
{
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c1": "data1",
            "c2": "data2" 
        } 
    }
}
```

GET on http://hostname/a/b returns

```
{
    "b": {
        "c1": "data1",
        "c2": "data2" 
    } 
}
```

I wanted to know the correct behavior of POST(and PUT) on http://hostname/a

```
{
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c1": "newdata" 
        } 
    }
}
```

Should it just update the c1 with value "newdata" or it should replace the whole resource b, thereby just containing c1 ( i.e. c2 is overwritten and doesn't exist anymore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have hit upon one of the most debated issues that I have seen in my time dealing with REST over the last few years.

Here's the simplistic answer:
The general consensus is that the HTTP PUT method has replace semantics and therefore c2 is overwritten and does not exist anymore.
The PATCH method was recently introduced to help people deal with partial updates.

Now, here are two complications to the scenario:

1. Why must PUT have replace semantics?  What are the negative effects of doing partial updates?  I've yet to hear a really convincing argument.

Actually, the HTTP spec does not specifically say PUT has replace semantics, it [says](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-12#section-7.6):

> The PUT method requests that the
> enclosed representation be stored at
> the effective request URI

however, it also says

> HTTP/1.1 does not define how a PUT
> method affects the state of an origin
> server.

2. It is accepted that if you assume PUT has replace semantics that a server may include some content in a representation that is not replaced.  e.g. If a representation contains links, doing a PUT of a representation that does not contain those links does not "delete" those links.  Same for a timestamp field, or last modified data.  The eternal question is how do we define which content is removed when omitted by the client and which stays because the server says so!

Personally, I avoided PUT because I found the "replace" semantics too constraining.  However, recently I am starting to be convinced by [Mike Kelly](http://restafari.blogspot.com/) and [Mike Amundsen](http://www.amundsen.com/) that maybe PUT should be considered more flexible than we currently give it credit for.

Comment: I didn't hear any convincing reason for not having partial updates, resulting in this question. I guess the only convincing reason could be that it adds more work. The second point is assuring because, we could have some fields to not be removed when omitted by the client.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you change a 'b' resource, why not you send POST(or PUT) to http://hostname/a/b instead of just http://hostname/a ? If something worth to be pointed/linked, it should be implemented as resource, according to RIA philosophy, and has got it's own URI.

Comment: The question remains the same, regardless of whether he did the PUT to a or b

Comment: The above is just an example. In our case c1 is an enable flag for a group of settings. So question still remained, that when we are just enabling the settings, can we only post the enabled field set to true.

Answer (score 0):

If you PUT to http://hostname/a what happens to cached copies of http://hostname/a/b? How long are they allowed to be out of sync?

If the answer is "they're not cached"...?

"The primary disadvantage of layered systems is that they add overhead and latency to the processing of data, reducing user-perceived performance. For a network-based system that supports cache constraints, this can be offset by the benefits of shared caching at intermediaries." -- A famous dissertation.

Comment: They can be invalidated immediately: http://restafari.blogspot.com/2010/04/link-header-based-invalidation-of.html